# Offset Rotation

Tags: java, rotation, offset

I have a code to rotate a piece in tetris game, but I don't know the meaning of xOffset and yOffset variables. Can you explain more about it for me ? Thanks so much !!

double xOffset = width/2.0 - .5;
        double yOffset = height/2.0 - .5;

```
    //Create a new body
    TPoint[] newBody = copyBody(body);
    for(TPoint p : newBody){

        //Rotoate 90 degrees counter clockwise about the origin
        double newX = p.x;
        double newY = p.y;

        newX -= xOffset;
        newY -= yOffset;

        double temp = newX;
        newX = -newY;
        newY = temp;

        newX += yOffset;
        newY += xOffset;

        p.x = (int) newX;
        p.y = (int) newY;
    }
    return new Piece(newBody);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell just by reading the snippet, but it seems to me that `xOffset` and `yOffset` values refer to the center point of the rotation.